# How to prove: $P(A\mid B\ \&\ C) = P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)-P(A\mid B)P(A\mid C)$

Tags: probability

How do we prove:
$$P(A\mid B\ \&\ C) = P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)-P(A\mid B)P(A\mid C)$$
if $B$ and $C$ are not mutually exclusive (and $B \neq$ C). Again not a homework question. I am a biologist trying to understand some math. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that the conditional probability distribution forms a probability function over your space?

Comment: Are any of them independant?

Comment: Try to draw it using Venn diagram

Comment: Ok, here is the deal: I am looking into Multi-variable optimization section under this [link](http://cbmm.mit.edu/sites/default/files/documents/CBMM_Optimization_Notes.html)
where they evaluate P(skipping) = P(skipping | working) + P(skipping | hungover) - P(skipping | working)*P(skipping | hungover) when both hungover & skipping. 
I have a trouble understanding the logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Under what hypothesis are we taking the formula? I don't think it is true in a general context. For instance, if $B=C$, the formula states

$$
P(A|B) = 2P(A|B) - P(A|B)^2
$$
$$
0 = P(A|B)[1-P(A|B)]
$$
which is not true in general.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense when $B = C$. Here I guess, $B \neq C$.

Comment: I've been trying to prove their equality rigorously but I think they are assuming things that I don't see. So far, I'm sure they are assuming independence of $B$ and $C$.

Intuitively, they are giving some weird version of the well known formula 

$$
P(E\cup F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(E\cap F)
$$

which can be written as 

$$
P(E\cup F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(E) P(F)
$$

if $E$ and $F$ are independent.

Comment: Yes, it is so confusing. I think they are saying, 
$P(A \mid B \ \cap C) = P (A\mid B \cup A\mid C)$